# How to change layer transparency without changing border lines?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, elevation, transparency-opacity

I have a raster image of elevations. I have added a vector shapefile that contains local political divisions. I want to keep the elevation colors, but I want to keep the black lines representing the political divisions as well.

I have reduced the transparency of the political divisions shapefile, but I can't figure out how to have this NOT affect the political division lines. Advice for reducing the fill transparency while keeping the black border colors at full?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way is to edit the aplha for the fill

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS Wien, you can click on the color properties and then set the opacity to 0%. The borders will be unaltered.[image: Opacity Slider]

Answer (score 2):

Good solutions,  another solution to this problem and one that I would have used until I read these other posts would be to create two layers from the same shapefile.  The first layer I would symbolize with the color you want to fill and no border outline,  then I would set this layer to the transparency you required.  The second layer would display all of the same data as the first but it would have the outline as solid black (or whatever color you wanted) and the fill color would be NO COLOR or blank.  I would leave this second layer at 0 transparency.  When both are loaded into the map you will get the fill color at the transparency you wanted and the outline at a different one.

This may not be the best solution but I have used it many times and it works great for me.

Comment: This methodology is still very good for sofware that don't have the alpha channel solution. I'd say yours is the "good old fashion" one !